# Do I have to use DisplayPort cables for 120Hz+ monitors?

Tags: display, hdmi, displayport, refresh-rate

I've read that for a lot of 120Hz, 144Hz and higher refresh rate, you have to use DisplayPort output from the GPU, and sometimes even 2 at the same time if the resolution is very high. But if I'm looking for a FullHD monitor with 144Hz refresh rate, can I use HDMI? Or does it depend on each monitor's model?

Comment: HDMI 2.1 is fully capable of 4K 120 Hz refresh rates.  You would have to look at the monitor’s specifications to determine if a given monitor supports it though.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the HDMI version. You'll need HDMI 1.3 or above for 1080p and 120 Hz or more.

EDIT:
Your monitor *and* graphics card do still need to support a 120 or 144 Hz refresh rate at the resolution you desire. [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Resolution_and_refresh_frequency_limits) works too.

The Wikipedia article has a really useful table:

[image: HDMI refresh rates table]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Refresh_frequency_limits_for_standard_video

Comment: Both the monitor and the GPU have to match this spec, right?

Comment: @user1306322 Of course

Answer (score -3):

HDMI supports 1080p 120hz, although it cannot use a 1080p 144hz mode. For that, a DisplayPort cable is required.